After login, move to a new page via POST in Mojolicious app
I am using Mojolicious (Lite) for a simple app where after login I want to redirect to a named route (already defined in the app) with the additonal requirement that I have a lot of JSON data to pass to it.
This route is also used by other parts of the app, for example, by clicking a button on the html page which ajax'es, via JS, to call this page with the JSON data.
My first thought is to declare this route as POST.
My question is how, after successful login, to move, from inside the Mojolicious app, to that page via a POST, with my JSON data. I have used Controller's redirect_to() before for GETting to the new page without significant JSON data but what if I have lots of JSON which is cumbersome to pass it on via url-params (e.g. http://example.com?p=mybigjsonencoded)?
EDIT: I am trying now to use controller's proxy->post_p() which proxies and gets that page which is then rendered. Isn't this cumbersome too?

You can't redirect using a POST request, heck you can't really even redirect with data unless you just use headers or query params. You should add that JSON to the users session, or store it as state somewhere else, like a database or cache. The flow would be something like: Login, append JSON to session or store in a database of some-sort, redirect to new route, access that stored JSON on the route you redirected to.

got it, thank you.

I don't know what you're really trying to do, but I think you may have this organized oddly.
First, wrap the final route with under so it requires authentication. You don't redirect, you just intercept and short-circuit.
Second, if the data you want to give to the final route doesn't come from the request, do you really need a POST (or even another request)? If everything can be discovered by the mere act of logging in, that information can either be put into the stash or developed by the final route. The controller action should be collating and adapting the data to send to the process-agnostic code that will return an answer, which the action then adapts for the view or the next process-agnostic thing it needs to use.
Note that Mojolicious doesn't do internal redirects, which is a nice Apache feature but not necessary when you have more control of routing built into the framework.
Third, a route (action, whatever) shouldn't really be a re-composable unit. If you have something that's reusable in your web app, make it a helper or regular subroutine that other routes can share. See what @Grinnz said in How can I internally redirect with Mojo? (which is what I just said).
In general, if you're facing problems with this sort of complexity, you're probably doing it wrong, where "wrong" means something outside the conceptual idea of the framework. Other frameworks might do it that way, but they aren't Mojolicious.
Your controllers should be coordinating resources, not providing the implementation of the lower level tasks that need to be done. One way to think about this is doing the same thing not through the controllers. Say you need to generate some sort of report. Can you provide all the information you need through the command line—perhaps through a mojo app command—and get the results right in your terminal with no web requests? If not, you may have butchered and scattered the meat of the solution throughout the web app, locking yourself into the web app as the only way to reuse those scraps.

Thanks. The routes i am talking about are under the cookie/session checker for filtering out unauthenticated access. I have now created a helper as per your advice and that works fine. But as a general query, and perhaps I am confused, after the login form is filled with user credentials, processed by the appropriate route and all is authenticated I need to move the user to the "next" page. I was doing that with a redirect_to(). But now I need somehow to move on to the "next" page via a POST. Any pointers on this?: How can I POST from a mojo route into another, externally at least.

Use under. As I noted in my answer, you have the wrong conceptual idea of now Mojo wants you to do this.
